# Counting and grouping elements from a db rown with CSV style values stored using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've been stuck on this for a while and thought I would run it by the experts!

I have a db table row with values stored in this format (I know - not a good idea but it's what I got).

```
4,4,3,4,2
4,4,3,2,2
2,4,3,4,2
4,2,3,4,2
```

Basically, each row has 4 values separated by a comma. Each 'spot' can have values 1 to 5.

What I'm looking to do it be able to count how many times I have 1 in the first position, 2 in the first position...., 1 in the second position, 2 in the second position, etc...

I've been playing with loops and explode() but I'm not getting far!

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you share the output you expect to get from this data please?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'format' it would generate but ideally, I'm thinking, 5 arrays (1 for each position) then I could just do a array_count_values($answer_array1) to get the counts of all different elements that show on position 1, then array_count_values($answer_array2) to get all the values that show on position 2...

Comment: Show what code you have so far

Comment: Decided to restart from scratch, and found a different solution... not very dynamic or elegant, but considering I have less than 5000 rows with this data I decide to do 5 db queries, each one using SUBSTR to only pickup one of each of the 5 values, then push each to an array, and loop my array to actually count and display the data. Not pretty.... but works! At this point it's all I can ask, although would still like to find a better solution. Thanks.